# PowerShell json foreach doesn't work

Tags: json, rest, api, foreach, powershell-3.0

I have a powershell script that makes an API request to return a list of users.

I am trying to get specific properties from each user.  However the for each loop doesn't seem to work.

The for each doesn't seem to loop though the users.

```
    foreach($user in $userList)
    {
        Write-Host($user.users.guid);
        Write-Host("Hello World");
    }
```

In this statesmen, I would expect to see the user GUID then Hello World.  what I get is all the GUIDS printed out side by side and then hello world at the end.

It doesn't seem to be looping though like other programming lang.

Here is my code.

```
   $userList = @();
   $userList = $null;
   $userList = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Headers $headers -Uri $Uri -
    Body ($body | ConvertTo-Json);

    foreach($user in $userList)
    {
        Write-Host($user.users.guid);
        Write-Host('Hello World');
    }
```

My goal is to take each user GUID and pass it to another method as it goes though the loop.  However, I cannot achieve this due to the foreach loop not working.

Could it be because it's now a json object?

Can you convert the Jaon object to an array or something?

Any suggestions?

Comment: `foreach($user in $userList.users.guid)`?

Comment: That doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually trying to turn json to json, but what you want is convert your response body from json string to object. In order to do this you need to use `ConvertFrom-Json` and not `ConvertTo-Json`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This helped somewhat.  So I take my $userList then ran the following:  $z = $userList | ConvertFrom-Json   the error i get back is exception type: system.arguemtnException, message: invalid json primitive: .

Comment: Can you copy response you get?

Comment: That is the Error.  message: invalid json primitive: .    I am wondering why it says that the period is an invalid primitive.  Could it be an issue with the data contained within the json?

Comment: I tried this command $test = $userList | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Jason, and the error I got back was Invalid JSON primitive: users.;

Comment: So i got the convertFrom-Json to work, however, the foreach loops still doesn't work.    it doesn't iterate though each record but instead prints them all out in one line.

Comment: what is the json string you are trying to parse?